# Any tips on how to make this XNA Gamepad code more efficient/reliable?

Tags: .net, xna, gamepad

Lately I've been working on the code for an ROV project. My goal was to configure an XBOX 360 controller to control the entire thing. So far getting everything to work is perfectly fine, except for the joysticks! I did get it to work somewhat for the drive motors, but I'd like if somebody could take a quick look at the code to see if there's a more efficient or more reliable way to do it. I found that sometimes when I would quickly flick the joystick, the motors wouldn't cut out when the joystick centred to 0. The thing about this project is that it's going to be used in a competition and I'd like to make sure it doesn't cop out on me during the competition. Anyway, here's the code I'm currently using. The only thing I'm really concerned about is the joysticks.

```
Imports Microsoft.Xna.Framework
Imports Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input
Public Class Form1
Dim WithEvents MC1 As Phidget21COM.PhidgetMotorControl
Dim WithEvents MC2 As Phidget21COM.PhidgetMotorControl

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    'Kills the power to the motors and disconnects the Phidget.
    MC1.Velocity(0) = 0
    MC1.Velocity(1) = 0
    MC1.Close()
    MsgBox("Now safe to remove devices")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Creates a new instance of the motor controller (For drives)
    MC1 = New Phidget21COM.PhidgetMotorControl
    MC1.Open(15100)
    MC1.WaitForAttachment(3000)
    'Checks phidget attached status
    If MC1.IsAttached = True Then
        CheckBox2.Checked = True
    Else
        CheckBox2.Checked = False
        MsgBox("Connection could not be established. Check hardware and restart the program.")
    End If
    'Checks joystick attached status
    JoyConnect.Text = ""
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    If GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsConnected = True Then
        JoyConnect.Text = "Controller Connected!"
        CheckBox1.Checked = True
    Else
        JoyConnect.Text = "Not Connected. :("
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub JoySticks()

    'Left Joystick
    Dim LY As Integer
    Dim LX As Integer
    LY = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Left.Y * 100
    LX = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Left.X * 100
    LX1.Text = LX
    LY1.Text = LY
    If LY > 0 Then
        MC1.Velocity(0) = LY
        MC1.Velocity(1) = LY
    ElseIf LY < 0 Then
        MC1.Velocity(0) = LY
        MC1.Velocity(1) = LY
    ElseIf LX > 0 Then
        MC1.Velocity(0) = LX
        MC1.Velocity(1) = LX * -1
    ElseIf LX < 0 Then
        MC1.Velocity(0) = LX
        MC1.Velocity(1) = LX * -1
    ElseIf LX Or LY = 0 Then           '<--- Seemed to fix some issues with
        MC1.Velocity(0) = 0            'the motors not stopping when the stick
        MC1.Velocity(1) = 0            'centred to 0.
    End If

    'Right Joystick
    Dim RY As Integer
    Dim RX As Integer
    RY = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Right.Y * 100
    RX = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Right.X * 100
    RY1.Text = RY
    RX1.Text = RX



End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Frequently updates the joysticks and motors. 1000 Updates/Second. (1ms)
    JoySticks()
End Sub
End Class
```